# Classification results on file

Tags: python, classification, report

I have a csv with 1.000 rows and two columns. The first column is some text and the second is a flag (1 or 0). I run some binary classification algorithms and got some f.score.
How can i get an output (saved to file) to show which rows go to 1 and which to 0, so i can manually compare the original flag with the algorithm's classification?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry i cant. I its ok if you cant help. I thought that there is a standard method to report that the classifier, classifies for example:  row 1 to class 1, row 2 to class 0 etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have got the result flags `(1 or 0)` which are stored in a variable say `results` **`(i.e. the prediction that you have made from your binary classification model)`**, and your data frame which holds the text and true flags is `df`, then you can do the following procedure to get the `1-flag texts` and `0-flag texts` into different files as follows

```
df['Predicted']=results
df1=df[df['Predicted']==1]
df2=df[df['Predicted']==0]
df1.to_csv('predicted1_flag.csv')
df2.to_csv('predicted0_flag.csv')
```

If you had provided the code snippets or output snaps, it would had become better but if you simply want to separate them as per the classes this would work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for the secrecy its complicated.

I got the f.score with this code

score = classifier.score(X_test, y_test)


Is there something like classifier.class, to hold the prediction classes?

Comment: You can use `classifier.predict(X_test)`, to get the predicted classes provided you are using scikit learn or any sort of simple classification problem. I mean without prediction what is the meaning of `score()`